# Save infopath web form library published on Sharepoint to SQL database

Tags: infopath, sql-server

I am very new to sharepoint. I have created an Infopath 2010 form template, which is hosted in Sharepoint 2010 library. I want to store the form data to SQL Database, so that I can create reports and manage permissions. Is there any way to do that? 
Please suggest possible solutions.